# No hyphenation on "section", "Table", etc. with Cleveref package

Tags: hyphenation, cleveref

I'd like to remove hyphenation at the end of a line on words like 'section', 'Table', 'Figure' etc. when using the \cref command with the Cleveref package. My current solution is the following:

```
\crefname{table}{\mbox{Table}}{Tables}
```

But  I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, since I'd have to repeat this command for figures, equations, etc.

I tried the following but believe that there is an infinite recursion issue:

```
\renewcommand{\cref}[1]{\cref{#1}}
```

So tried this, but to the same issue:

```
\newcommand{\crefboxed}[1]{\mbox{\cref{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\cref}[1]{\crefboxed{#1}}
```

Any insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering ti the infinite recursion problem:

```
\let\oldcref\cref
```

and after that

```
\renewcommand{\cref}[1]{\mbox{\oldcref{#1}}}
```

or

```
\def\cref#1{\mbox{\oldcref{#1}}}
```

About the problem of more arguments that Mico mentioned you could do this:

```
\def\cref#1{\foreach\arg[count=\j from 1] in {#1}{\xdef\NumArgs{\j}}\foreach \argument[count=\i from 1] in {#1}{\ifnum\i=1\mbox{\oldcref{\argument}}\else \ifnum\i=\NumArgs{} and \ref{\argument}\else, \ref{\argument}\fi\fi}}
```

Could work only for same type of arguments (only tables or only figures etc)... Anyway my answer was about the infinite recursion... (But thanks for the comment @Mico)

PS: You need `pgffor` package for this..

Comment: Thank you for that insight. Is there a benefit to using \renewcommand vs. \def?

Comment: Umm, this method has a *serious downside* if the argument of `\cref` contains two or more arguments. In that cases, this method will not only suppress hyphenation in the word `figure` (or `table`, or whatever), but also prevent any and all line breaks elsewhere in the cross-references. E.g., if `\cref{fig:2,fig3}` is supposed to output the string `Figures 2 and 3`, the presence of `\mbox` will also disallow a line break between the substrings `Figures 2` and `and 3`. That's not what the OP specified -- or might conceivably want, really.

Comment: @likethevegetable it generally adviced to use `\renewcommand` in LaTeX ... `\def` is a TeX command that for example does not informs you that the command is already defined ... But I use `\def` often (that's my problem I suppose). Something not about this example: Just keep in mind, that `\def` can work if `\cref` is or is not defined... but you have to be careful with `\newcommand` if already defined or `\renewcommand` if not defined.

Comment: @koleygr - Many thanks for addressing the issue I raised. I'm afraid I can't get your code to run as is (and, yes, it's not because I failed to load `pgffor`).

Comment: @Mico ... Sorry ... I lost a `\fi` and an `old` because didn't tested at all. Thanks for informing ... Now it is tested.

Comment: (but prints `table` instead of `tables` ...)

Comment: @koleygr - I hate to create the impression that I am out to torture you, as it's certainly not my intenton; however, I may be succeeding anyway. :-( In addition to not rendering the label in plural form (as you've noted too, in the preceding comment), the updated code also doesn't seem to handle cases such as `\cref{tab:1,,tab:2,,tab:3,,tab:4}`, where the `,,` particles are meant to disrupt `cleveref`'s attempt to sort and collapse consecutively numbered cross-references, i.e., to generate `Tables 1 to 4`.

Comment: Also it doesn't handle the case `\cref{tab:1,tab:1}` that `\cref{}` handles! hahaha kidding ... Thanks Mico ... Anyway as said I didn't tried to give a solution of not breaking the "figure" or "table" word ... but just answered about OPs original problem on infinite recursion. Thanks. (Already upvoted your answer)

Answer (score 5):

If you wish to suppress hyphenation of the words `section`, `table`, and `figure` when using `\cref`, you will probably also want to suppress hyphenation of these words in other circumstances. If that's the case, simply run

```
\hyphenation{section table figure}
```

in the preamble.

If you do wish to limit hyphenation suppression of `figure`, `table`, and `section` to what's output by `\cref`, just add the following instructions to the preamble (after loading `cleveref`, naturally:

```
\crefname{section}{\mbox{section}}{\mbox{sections}}
\Crefname{figure}{\mbox{Figure}}{\mbox{Figures}}
\crefname{table}{\mbox{table}}{\mbox{tables}}
```

If you happen to run `\Cref` as well as `\cref`, you'll also need to add

```
\Crefname{section}{\mbox{Section}}{\mbox{Sections}}
\Crefname{figure}{\mbox{Figure}}{\mbox{Figures}}
\Crefname{table}{\mbox{Table}}{\mbox{Tables}}
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't know of the \hyphenation{...} command.. thank you very much, this solves the problem and more.